# Statistics - Mean , Median, Mode , Standard deviation.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means, median

A vendor states that over the past year, the mean monthly sales were 10,000 with a standard deviation of 2,000. The sales in most months, however, were below 8,000 and the most frequent monthly sales were 7,500. What were her yearly sales?

Is the answer $120000? Since summation of observations is mean times number of observations. The number of observations being 12 (months in a year). But then why are we given median, mode and standard deviation? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the yearly sale is $$12\times 10000 =120000 $$

We do not have to use the other information to find the total sale.

Are they asking for more analysis, for example how many months of $7500$?

Comment: No, this is the complete question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the mean per month is $10,000$, then yearly total is the mean per month multiplied by the months in the year, so
$$12 \times 10,000 = 120,000$$

The rest of the data is useless to this end